# identifierForVendor crash as EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, crash, exc-bad-access, uidevice

I have hit that issue not very frequently and all version of hit issues are more than IOS 11.

This is one of crash log:

> OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1.2 (15B202)
>
> Baseband Version:    n/a
>
> Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000101831801e0
>
> VM Region Info: 0x101831801e0 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1097952920033
>
> ```
>  REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
>
>  MALLOC_NANO (reserved) 00000001d8000000-00000001e0000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
> ```
>
> --->
>         UNUSED SPACE AT END
>
> Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>
> Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
>
> Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
>
> Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog:
>
> None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:
>
> 0   ???                            0x00000101831801e0 0 + 1106005983712
>
> 1   MobileCoreServices             0x0000000183188af0 -[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForVendor] + 192
>
> 2   UIKit                          0x000000018ad5cd48 -[UIDevice identifierForVendor] + 56
>
> 3   Test-Demo-iOS                  0x000000010073cc4c __35+[ getInstance_:vendorKey:]_block_invoke + 160
>
> 4   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000180d75048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
>
> 5   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000180d78710 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 60
>
> ...

This code appeared in the beginning of viewDidLoad. And in getInstance_, my original code is:

```
    c_inst->dbg("_device_id", [[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]UTF8String]);
```

This code can hit this issue. And I made some changes but still failed to avoid this crash:

```
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if (device){
        NSUUID *idfv = [device identifierForVendor];
        if (idfv){
             c_inst->dbg("_device_id", [[idfv UUIDString] UTF8String]);
        }
    }
```

Have anybody hit this issue and know the root cause for that crash? 
I also need someone help give me some suggestions that fix this issue.

Thanks